# Setting the data step property of shield ui

Tags: shieldui

I am trying to set a datetime X axis for my Shield UI Chart, but am some confused about the data step. I need to have a one day increments, but I see:

```
dataStep: 24 * 3600 * 1000
```

I assume, that 24*3600 are the seconds for the day, but what is the 1000 multiplier used for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, but are forgetting, that the chart is taking into account milliseconds, instead of seconds. Therefore one day is not only 24*3600 seconds, but 24*3600*1000 milliseconds. This will give you one day increment on your X axis.